# Module Not Found - No module named

Tags: python, module

Here's my Python folder structure

```
-project
----src
------model
--------order.py
------hello-world.py
```

Under `src` I have a folder named `model` which has a Python file called `order.py` which contents follow:

```
class SellOrder(object):
    def __init__(self,genericName,brandName):
        self.genericName = genericName
        self.brandName = brandName
```

Next my `hello-world.py` is inside the `src` folder, one level above `order.py`:

```
import model.order.SellOrder

order = SellOrder("Test","Test")

print order.brandName
```

Whenever I run `python hello-world.py` it results in the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello-world.py", line 1, in <module>
    import model.order.SellOrder
ImportError: No module named model.order.SellOrder
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: what should be the contents if __init__.py?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: `__init__.py` can be empty or can contain code. it is common for projects to expose their primary / public classes at the package level. In your case you could add `from model.order import SellOrder` so that other code can do  `from project import Sellorder` instead of `from project.model.order import SellOrder`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

All modules in Python have to have a certain directory structure. [You can find details here.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Create an empty file called `__init__.py` under the `model` directory, such that your directory structure would look something like that:

```
.
└── project
    └── src
        ├── hello-world.py
        └── model
            ├── __init__.py
            └── order.py
```

Also in your `hello-world.py` file change the import statement to the following:

```
from model.order import SellOrder
```

That should fix it

P.S.: If you are placing your `model` directory in some other location (not in the same directory branch), you will have to modify the python path using `sys.path`.

Comment: also it's considered good practice not to have a `src` directory. that makes sense too because if you import your code somewhere else you should be able to `import project.model` and not `project.src.model`.

Comment: Very late to this thread, but I have the exact same structure as above, and using the solution above, I still can only run my program (`locust -f src\main.py ...`) if I use `from src.module.submodule import main`.   Even with __init__.py in place.   Maybe my `cwd` should be inside `src`?

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working. I have `__init__.py` in every folder but it still cannot be imported. Pycharm didn't show up with any errors, but the terminal kept showing up errors.

Comment: For some reason it works when I run the python file. But when executing the same commands in the interactive mode, it does not work. Very intriguing.

Comment: Yeah, adding `__init__.py` doesn't fix this issue for me. Even in the same directory (i.e. both scripts are under the same folder)

Comment: @Dekriel @wesmir If the project is setup as described in the [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), it should work. However, there are many reasons why your particular case does not. Easy things to try: (1) Check your `PYTHONPATH`; (2) Check that your package is in the `sys.path`; (3) Make sure you are importing correctly (path is proper); (4) Make sure your package name does not clash with an existing/installed package...

Without an actual error, there is very little I can infer what might be going on.

Answer (score 26):

If it's your root module just add it to `PYTHONPATH` (PyCharm usually does that)

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<root module path>
```

for Docker:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:<root module path in container>"
```

Comment: If you're going to be running this code from your root module, it is very convenient to have the current directory, `.`, in your PYTHONPATH, if it's not there already. Linux: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.`. Windows: `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;.`

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I was calling different scripts on my project depending on the parameter passed to `docker-compose up`, and this was the only way the imports started to solve correctly on docker compose and not only when running it via Python directly.

Answer (score 10):

you need a file named `__init__.py` (two underscores on each side) in every folder in the hierarchy, so one in `src/` and one in `model/`. This is what python looks for to know that it should access a particular folder. The files are meant to contain initialization instructions but even if you create them empty this will solve it.

Comment: In `src`, `init.py` is not needed, see @Rafazz`s answer

Answer (score 4):

It's easier if you use this code

```
python3 -m module.sub_module
```

For example:

```
python3 -m entrypoint.settings
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add your project root directory to environment variable: PYTHONPATH.
so for the below project structure, just add Rootdir path(For e.g: add E:\Projects\Rootdir) in PYTHONPATH.

```
Rootdir
└── pkg2
    ├── b.py
    ├── c.py
     └── pkg2
      ├── b.py
      ├── c.py
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying to add the path using:

```
pip show
```

on command prompt and using

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/myname/pythonfiles")
```

and didn't work. Also got SSL error when trying to install the module again using conda this time instead of pip.

I simply copied the module that wasn't found from the path "Mine was in

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages
```

so I copied it to `'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages'`

Answer (score 1):

I had same error. For those who run python scripts on different servers, please check if the python path is correctly specified in shebang. For me on each server it was located in different dirs.

Comment: That's why you should never use `#!/usr/bin/python` but `#!/usr/bin/env python` (or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for Python3, or possibly `#!/usr/bin/env python3.8` for a specific version). This will also work when using virtual environments, while the first form won't.

Answer (score 1):

I only use Python as a secondary language and probably made a newbie-error. I had similar problem and my error was calling:

```
import requests
```

I got the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.adapters'; 'requests' is not a package
```

Turns out the file I created in the same folder named "requests.py" made a conflict. Renaming the file made it work again.

Answer (score 1):

It's also important to not that sometimes the solution is a lot simpler than you think. None of the solutions above worked for me and after some time I came to realise that it was just that I had a leading space in the filename for my '**init**.py' file.

Removed the leading space ... crisis averted.

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to make sure the module is installed for **all** versions of python

You can check to see if a module is installed for python by running:

pip uninstall *moduleName*

If it is installed, it will ask you if you want to delete it or not. My issue was that it was installed for python, but not for python3. To check to see if a module is installed for python3, run:

python3 -m pip uninstall *moduleName*

After doing this, if you find that a module is not installed for one or both versions, use these two commands to install the module.

- **pip install *moduleName***
- **python3 -m pip install *moduleName***

Comment: This is not what the question is asking

Comment: Well, this helped me. Those modules were working through PyCharm but when I ran my program through Terminal it showed `ModuleNotFoundError` and this solution fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode, what worked for me was I changed the interpreter of my IDE, here is a quick snapshot:
[image]

I install my packages through pip3, it appears to be like my Homebrew handles all of the packages I installed previously, so that's the tweak I had to make!!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution depends on where you are running this code from.

If you try running `python hello-world.py` (from the src directory), you would have to do the following two things for this to work:

1. Change the import line in hello-world.py to `from model.order import SellOrder`
2. If not already there, add to your system environment variable. Key `PYTHONPATH`, value `.`

Answer (score 0):

I have write on Powershell
$env:PYTHONPATH = "C:\Users\adolfo\Desktop\borrar"
with the route of the root folder of the project

Comment: I'm voting to delete this answer. Because this is the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164141/7758804), which already states to update `PYTHONPATH`, I can only assume it was posted as a "thank you" or "confirmation". Please don't add "thank you", or "confirmation" answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/34247909)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34247909)

Answer (score 0):

Create a setup.py file.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name= 'any_name', version= '1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

then in cmd give:

```
pip install -e .
```

Answer (score -2):

if you are using python 3 then try the below command. I was facing similar issue , this fixed my problem

pip3 install

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by deleting previous python2 and only using python3 which is working fine on windows 10

Answer (score -7):

you need to import the function so the program know what that is here is example:

```
import os 
import pyttsx3
```

i had the same problem first then i import the function and it work so i would really recommend to try it