# How to call Python script from another directory

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

```
Django project folder structure

    project (source root)
    -->apps
    ---->**app1**
    ----->admin.py
    ----->init.py
    ----->apps.py
    ----->models.py
    ----->urls.py
    ----->views.py
    ----->callscript2.py
    ----->**myscipt-folder**
    ------>script1.py
    ------>script2.py
    ------>__init__.py
    ---->**app2**
    ----->admin.py
    ----->init.py
    ----->apps.py
    ----->models.py
    ----->urls.py
    ----->views.py
    ----->sample.py (must be able to call the script2 from app1, myscript folder)
    ---->**app3**
```

When I call the file from `sample.py`

```
from apps.app1.myscipt-folder import script1
```

I get the following error

```
from apps.app1.myscipt-folder import script1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.app1'; 'apps' is not a package
```

But when I test it inside the `callscript2.py` it works fine. What do you think I do wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `from apps.app1.myscipt-folder import script1`
Try this:

```
from app1.myscipt-folder import script1
```