# Module not found when importing a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

```
import Stock
```

Whenever I try to do this I get this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Stock'

My Stock file is located in the same folder as `stock_test` (this is where I do `import Stock`) and I have an init file in the same folder.

I'm not really sure what I'm missing here, any help would be appreciated.

Stock file has everything that is working and I need it to import.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found)

Comment: pls update full error message

Answer (score 0):

I make a folder based on your discription. Below is the structure.

```
├── Stock.py
├── Stock_sub
│   ├── Stock_test2.py
│   └── __init.py
├── Stock_test.py
└── __init__.py
```

For `Stock.py`,

```
def test():
    print('Stock.py is imported')
```

Now if you want to use `test` function in `Stock_test.py`, because they are in the same folder, you can import Stock just by

```
import Stock
Stock.test()
```

If you want to use `Stock.py` in `Stock_test2.py`, because they are in the different folder, so you need to **specify the search path of import package**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

import Stock
Stock.test()
```

I use function here, the same if you want to import Class.