# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projeler_ile_python'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

i did everythin but still i got ModuleNotFoundError: No module error.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found)

Comment: probably it could work but guess i couldnt do it propery.Can u help about what should i write exacly ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you r importing something which is not installed. you can install it using `pip install projeler_ile_python`. If you install it properly then it will work fine.
or create `__init__.py` file inside projeler_ile_python folder because if there is not any `__init__.py` file that folder is simple folder not a package.

Comment: but projeler_ile_python is just a folder how i can install it via pip ?