# GeoPandas not getting imported

Tags: python, python-import, geopandas

I am trying to import the GeoPandas module (which I had recently installed on my laptop) in a Jupyter notebook but it returning this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a62d01c1d62e> in <module>
----> 1 import geopandas as gpd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

I am certain that geopandas installed correctly. Can someone please suggest a fix?

Comment: try fresh installation using https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: These answers might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be installed in the right kernel for your jupyter notebook. One way to fix this is to run `%pip install geopandas` in a cell in your notebook. Then you can restart the kernel and you should be able to import it.

## edit

just tried this out again and I had to add a `--user` to the magic command. The final command should look like `%pip install geopandas --user`

Comment: I tried that command and toward the end of it, the message this command returned read 
`Installing collected packages: munch, click-plugins, cligj, fiona, pyproj, geopandas
Successfully installed click-plugins-1.1.1 cligj-0.5.0 fiona-1.8.13.post1 geopandas-0.7.0 munch-2.5.0 pyproj-2.6.0
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.` 

but I am still getting the same error as in my original question. Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Did you restart your kernel after?

Comment: The original command worked for me after I restarted the kernel a couple times. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to manually install the libraries as i could not import them although they were present in pip list of installed packages.

I went to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/), where I downloaded the compatible version for GDAL, Pyproj, Fiona, Shapely and Geopandas.

Then I manually installed them using:

pip install ***the file path***