# error while using a class and importing it as a module

Tags: python

I have these lines in these files:

config.py:

```
from main import main as m
```

main.py:

```
from pycocoevalcap.cider.cider import Cider
```

pycocoevalcap/cider/cider.py:

```
from cider_scorer import CiderScorer
```

and in "cider_scorer.py" file, there is a class named "CiderScorer".
but when I run "config.py" with CommandLine on Windows, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cider_scorer'
```

I can't find what's wrong here?

this is the code: https://github.com/yicheng-w/CommonSenseMultiHopQA

Comment: Presuming this is in a package you probably want `from .cider_scorer import ...`.  But you do need to add details like **where** this `cider_scorer` is ... you added details about every module **except the one that can’t be found**

Comment: clone this package : https://github.com/ruotianluo/cider

Because I think you took it from here.

And read the readme file. Be careful the module can be in a subfolder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found)

Comment: @donkopotamus  as I said there is a cider_scorer.py. there is a class named CiderScorre in that file. you can find it here : https://github.com/yicheng-w/CommonSenseMultiHopQA/blob/master/src/pycocoevalcap/cider/cider_scorer.py

Answer (score -1):

The cause of this error is usually one of three causes:

1. path of module is wrong
2. module name is incorrect
3. library module not installed (not your case)
   checkout:
   [1]: https://pytutorial.com/how-to-solve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-in-python
   [2]: [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks to your contribution. If you know the question has been asked and answered before, please don't create a new answer that refers to the previous one, but flag the question as duplicate. Regarding your answer itself: could you explain what "path of module is wrong" means and how it can be solved? Bullet 2 and 3 do not apply, so seems not useful to mention here, IMHO.

Comment: that's the structure of the code and I checked it many times, path and name is correct. I need to add the path of that module in OS path? this is the code: https://github.com/yicheng-w/CommonSenseMultiHopQA/tree/master