# ImportError: No module named pageObjects.LoginPage

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I am trying to implement a `POM`(Page Object Model) in `PyCharm` by creating packages named `PageObjects` and `testCases`. However, as soon as I run my test class in `Python`, I get

> ImportError: No Module named pageObjects.LoginPage

**Screenshot of my project structure**

[image]

**AutoTest.py**

```
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting")
from pageObjects.LoginPage import LoginPage



class AutoTest(unittest.TestCase):
    baseURL = "https://10.2.5.215:33000/viewTopUpRequest"
    username = "ezltest2svc"
    password = "Password123!"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver.get(cls.baseURL)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)


    def test_login(self):
        lp = LoginPage(self.driver)
        lp.setUsername(self.username)
        lp.setPassword(self.password)
        lp.clickLogin()
        lp.clickUtil()



    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        print("Test Completed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='C:/Users/lukegoh/Desktop/Python Projects/SoftwareAutomationTesting/reports'))
```

**LoginPage.py**

```
class LoginPage:

    textbox_username_name="username"
    textbox_password_name="password"
    button_login_xpath="//button[contains(text(),'Login')]"
    utilityTopUp_xpath ="//div[@id='wrapper']/div/ul/li[9]/a"

    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver=driver


    def setUsername(self,username):
        self.driver.find_element_by_name(self.textbox_username_name).send_keys(username)


    def setPassword(self, password):
        self.driver.find_element_by_name(self.textbox_password_name).send_keys(password)


    def clickLogin(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.button_login_xpath).click()

    def clickutil(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.utilityTopUp_xpath).click()
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved it by adding `__init__.py` empty file inside the packages I've created.

Link can be found here: [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found)