# No module named PageObjects found

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

file Test2.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from PageObjects.LoginPage import LoginPage
from Resources.TestData import TestData as td
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner


opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
  })

class UpdatePersonalInfo(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opt)

    def test_update_firstName_lastname_jobtitle(self):

if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main(testRunner=HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='..\\Reports'))
```

1. run python3.8 Test2.py
   => `No module named PageObjects`
2. how to resolve this pb please i created `__init__.py` on each folder on the project and same problem persist

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65867641/7598774