# Python module not found even though module was created

Tags: python

This is my current directory structure, I am trying to import a function from `src/helpers/log.py` to `src/data/download_dataset.py`. I have followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found) but it still does not work.

```
|-- AUTHORS.rst
|-- CONTRIBUTING.rst
|-- HISTORY.rst
|-- LICENSE
|-- MANIFEST.in
|-- Makefile
|-- README.rst
|-- data
|   |-- external
|   |-- interim
|   |-- processed
|   `-- raw
|       `-- wine-quality.csv
|-- docs
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- authors.rst
|   |-- conf.py
|   |-- contributing.rst
|   |-- history.rst
|   |-- index.rst
|   |-- installation.rst
|   |-- make.bat
|   |-- readme.rst
|   `-- usage.rst
|-- dvc_mlflow
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- dvc_mlflow.py
|-- logs
|-- models
|-- requirements_dev.txt
|-- setup.cfg
|-- setup.py
|-- src 
|   |-- data
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- download_dataset.py
|   |-- features
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   |-- helpers
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- log.py
|   `-- models
|       `-- __init__.py
|-- tests
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- test_dvc_mlflow.py
`-- tox.ini
```

I am importing the file `log_error` in `src/data/download_dataset.py` like so:

```
from helpers.log import log_error
```

But when I try to run the file using `python3 src/data/download_dataset.py` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'`. I am a bit confused because I already added in the `__init__.py` files in each of the directories to make them modules but the issue still persists.

Comment: You are running it from the root directory of the project which only has `src` in it. So it either needs to be `from src.helpers.log import log_error` or you need to run it from `src` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `sys.path.append` method. Whatever modules you want to import, find the path to those modules and pass it to the function.

Example:

If my current working directory is `/home/user_name/Desktop/Scripts/Main.py` and I want to import some file `Factorial.py` which is at `/home/user_name/Documents/OtherScripts/`, I can do the following

```
# Inside your Main.py file
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/user_name/Documents/OtherScripts/")
from Factorial import *
```

Comment: This works I used `sys.path.append("/Users/yravindranath/dvc_mlflow/")` but it seems rather hacky, isn't there another way without having to append the path?

Comment: I am not sure about the correct way of doing it. Yeah, it's hacky. But it works :)

Comment: @yudhiesh Typically I do `sys.path.append`s with relative paths determined automatically. Your main file is in this directory `d = os.path.dirname(__file__)` so from there you can add `f"{d}/folder1/folder2"` or even go backwards `f"{d}/../parent folder"`. That way your code can be moved around and always work without having to do manuals adjustments to the paths as long as the general structure of the project is intact.

Comment: @Guimoute thanks for pointing that out, in that case then this answer is more suitable than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You are running it from the root directory of the project which only has `src` in it. So it either needs to be `from src.helpers.log import log_error` or you need to run it from `src` directory.

In general, you'd want to name your `src` directory with the same name as your project, so imports look logical.

Comment: When I try `python3 download_dataset.py` and `from helpers.log import log_error` I get the same error. When I run `from src.helpers.log import log_error ` and running `python3 src/data/download_dataset.py` I get `No module named 'src'`. I updated the question with the full dir structure.

Comment: Now you are running it from `data` directory. Try running it from the root directory

Comment: What python version do you use? You might also need to add `__init__.py` to the `src` directory.

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.8 but that does not solve it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found an even simpler way that did not resort to me having to append the path using `sys.path.append()`, just needed to set the python path in the command line using `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/project/"`.

Comment: Every time you work on another project, you have to do this again.