# Trouble importing a module that itself imports another module in Python

Tags: python, python-import

Python version: 3.8.5

File structure

```
MainDir
   |
   | Utils --|
   |         | module1.py
   |         | module2.py
   |
   | Tests --|
             | test.py
```

`module1.py` imports `module2.py`
`test.py` imports `module1.py`

When I run `python Tests/test.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Utils.module1
  File "<abspath>/MainDir/Utils/module1.py", line 16, in <module>
    import module2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

I've tried the following:

1.) [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found)

2.)

```
$export PYTHONPATH="$PWD"
```

3.) I've tried putting the `test.py` file at the same level as the `Utils` directory.

4.)

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../MainDir")
```

And several variations thereof.

They all failed.

The only thing that worked was just putting `test.py` in the `Utils` directory and running it from there. But I know there has to be a way to get it to work when it's in its own directory.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

The selected answer worked when trying to run `test.py`, but it broke when trying to run `module1.py`.

After some more research, running it with the `-m` flag and package syntax worked; in my case:

```
python -m Utils.module1
```

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this problem.

Comment: you need to add a `__init__.py` file to the `Utils` directory so that python recognizes it as a package...  [check the doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: @raphael Should have mentioned that I already tried that. Didn't work; had the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use relative imports.

So perhaps something like :

```py
# in module1.py

import .module2
```

Relative imports mean that you are not trying to import from the `__main__` file but from the current file (in your case module1.py).

Edit :
Just realised I am stupid. This works for modules, not individual files.
Please try again with `from . import module2`

Comment: Just tried it, but it gave me an ```invalid syntax``` error pointing right at the dot preceding ```module2```...

Comment: The edited answer worked beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you structure your project like [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/) you can use this. Also it is recommended to use relative import inside your packages

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

Comment: What's the difference between ```sys.path.insert()``` and ```sys.path.append()```?

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony, the difference is that the new path is added at the beginning of the list, shifting everything else to the right. It affects the order things are looked into (first or last ?). If you don't care about that, then insert(0, ...) might be slightly longer (O(N) instead of O(1) for append).