# ModuleNotFoundError when importing a module that is importing itself another module

Tags: python, python-3.x

**File structure:**

```
AppFolder/
  |
  |-- main.py
  |
  |-- Google\
            |
            |-- client.py
            |
            |-- synchronization.py
```

In my `main.py`I'm trying to import `synchronization.py`. In  `synchronization.py` I'm importing `client.py`

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'client'` with my files configured like this :

**main.py**

```
import Google.synchronization as googleCalendar

def main():
    googleCalendar.getEvents()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**synchronization.py**

```
import client

def main():
    """Connects the application with a google API"""
    global service
    service = client.main()

def getEvents():
    return service.events().list(calendarId = 'primary')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Someone else had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727867/trouble-importing-a-module-that-itself-imports-another-module-in-python) and I tried multiple things like  `from Google.synchronization import *` or `from . import synchronization`  but nothing changed.

The only thing that "resolved" the issue is putting the imports inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` for `main.py`and `synchronization`like this :

**synchronization.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import client
    main()
```

But now, when I run main.py, I get the error : `NameError: name 'service' is not defined`. And I don't know how to repair this new issue.

Is there another way to import my files that could alleviate both problems? Or another way to create my variable `service`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `import .client`

Comment: @saedx1 In ```main.py``` I'm getting a syntax error, I also tried ```Google.client```but it doesn't change anything. Or do you mean in ```synchronization.py```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from .import client

def main():
    """Connects the application with a google API"""
    service = client.main()
    return service

def getEvents():
    return main().events().list(calendarId = 'primary')
```

Comment: the ```service```variable is a Resource built by a google method to interract with the API so I don't really know how to declare the variable before.
I tried in the `__name__ == '__main__'` to create the variable but I'm still getting the ```NameError```

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you try that

Comment: Thanks it's working! Do you have any idea why the `service` variable was not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing this way:

```
from .client import main as client_main
```

Comment: In ```synchronization.py``` I'm getting ```ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```. I think it's because client and synchronization are in the same folder. So I tried ``from client import main as client_main``` but it doesn't change anything when I run ```main.py```