# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'github'

Tags: python, github, pygithub

trying to import github (PyGithub) but it keeps giving the same error, even though the lib is fully installed.

Code:

```
from github import Github
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...path", line 1, in <module>
    from github import Github
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'github'
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found)

Comment: Installed with "python3 -m pip install PyGithub" (also shows up in ... pip freeze).
I am not sure how the other post helps me with this question.

Comment: Are you running the REPL with `python3` command?

Answer (score 5):

This will install the package.

```
pip3 install PyGithub
```

If you're getting the same error that could be due to circular imports. Rename if you have any .py files named "github.py" in your work folder.