# Custom module not found python

Tags: python, import, module, python-import

I'm building a simple telegram bot and i need to create many .py files to order the project but when I try to run the code, the terminal displays this error message:

```
    from consts.Key import Values
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'consts'
```

The project folder is structured like this:

```
|
|__ main.py
|__ basics
  |
  |__ consts
  |  |__ __init__.py
  |  |__ Key.py
  |
  |__ games
  |  |
  |  |__ __init.py
  |  |__ FindTheNumberGame.py
  |
  |__ __init__.py
  |__ StartApp.py
```

[I have already read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found) but it does not work still.

I need to import the Key module in StartApp.py to use the bot token and now I'm doing it in this way:

```
from consts.Key import Values
```

In this line, Values is a class that extends the Enum class.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I tried by replicating your folder structure, but I don't get any errors.

Comment: Actually, the problem shows up just when I run the program. The editor does not show any error, on the contrary, it can find the references in the other files. That's why I cannot figure out what's the matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#/consts/**init**.py

```py
#this module include from consts
from . Key import Values
```

#main.py

```py
from consts import Values
```

more information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)