# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: module, scrapy

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvwN3.png)

Hello! It's my first Scrapy project and I'm not enought skilled in this.

When I run code and type in terminal  "scrapy crawl 'name spider'", then get this problem.
However, even type something else, happens same(

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrLpj.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE4AI.png)

A few images how its looks in folders

What should I do for running succesfuly my code?
How to fix it? Any ideas? Thank u!

Comment: Potential answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233140/python-module-not-found  and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named,  also, have you tried "pip install scrapy"?

Comment: Yeah, I have already try it, but still doesn't work. My structure looks good as it seems to me and I've all needed files

Comment: Change your spider's `name` attribute to `"violity_spider"` then run `scrapy crawl violity_spider -o filename.json`

Comment: Thanks for correction. However, nothing was changed.

Comment: (venv1) PS D:\pythonProject> cd pricescraper
(venv1) PS D:\pythonProject\pricescraper> cd spiders
(venv1) PS D:\pythonProject\pricescraper\spiders> scrapy crawl violity_spider -o filename.json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pricescraper'

Comment: that means you are trying to import pricescraper in a different module.  Go through each of the files in your project and make sure you don't have any files trying to import pricescraper

Comment: Thank you! That was a problem. I created another folder with name "pricescraper" and fill in all files from folder 'pricescraper'